# Transparência CSS

Tags: css

Eu sei que se usar opacity em uma div, todos os elementos dentro dela também ficarão opacos. E sei também que posso usar RGBA para fazer um elemento com uma cor de fundo ficar transparente, mas, como faço pra "transparentizar" um background com uma imagem? É possível isso?

Comment: Você quer usar uma imagem como máscara de transparência?

Comment: Não, quero usar uma imagem com background aplicando opacidade pelo CSS diretamente. Mas não sei se isso é possível.

Comment: Você quer uma div que fique sobre outros elementos, que essa div tenha uma imagem de fundo, e que esse fundo seja semi-transparente via CSS. Entendi corretamente agora?

Comment: Não rs. Segue link ai. http://drop.studiogt.com.br/g8/index.php/receitas-interna

Comment: Essa imagem que vem de lado e fica por cima dessa div com uma imagem de background. Preciso que o bg fiquei opaco.

Comment: poste uma imagem simulando o efeito desejado, senão fica difícil de entender. Qual é o problema do opacity no seu caso específico? Não dá pra aplicar apenas na div desejada?

Comment: Acho que você quer fazer um [lightbox](http://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/). Seria isso?

Comment: No exemplo que você mostrou, trata-se de uma div por trás com a imagem no seu tamanho normal e uma div superior com a imagem em um tamanho menor. Para aplicar o efeito de opacidade você já citou na pergunta uma forma de fazer.

Comment: Sua dúvida é sobre opacidade e não sobre sobreposição? Aplicar opacity no elemento em background apenas?

Answer (score 2):

É meio difícil fazer o que você quer apenas com CSS, sem mexer no HTML, mas dependendo do resto do seu HTML atual, isso pode funcionar ou precisar só de alguns ajustes:

```
#seu-elemento {
    z-index: 1;
    position: relative;
}

#seu-elemento:before {
    background: url(sua/imagem/de/fundo.png);
    opacity: .6; 
    z-index: -1;
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 0; 
    left: 0;
    width: 100%; 
    height: 100%;  
}
```

Veja uma [demonstração aqui](http://jsfiddle.net/dnbrx0rb/2/).

Answer (score 2):

É possível fazer isto usando pseudo-seletores para simular um background transparente apenas com CSS e sem elementos extras seu DOM:

```
.conteudo:before{
    content:'';
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    position:absolute;
    z-index:1;
    background:url(sua-imagem.png);
    opacity:sua-opacidade;
}
.conteudo *{
    z-index:2;
    position:relative;
}
```

O que o código acima faz é criar um pseudo-seletor e setar ele com uma opacidade que você define, de forma que a imagem usada por ele ficaria transparente, ao mesmo tempo em que o resto do elemento continuaria com opacidade de 100%.

Exemplo completo: **[`FIDDLE`](http://jsfiddle.net/cg1pku3n/)**

Answer (score 1):

**Sim**, ao invés de utilizar a propriedade `opacity` utilize `linear-gradient`. Você pode "mesclar" vários valores e buscar o resultado de *background* que está precisando.

Utilizando `opacity`, os elementos filhos também serão afetados. Por exemplo:

```css
div {
    background: url(http://static-files.cdnandroid.com/1f/48/ef/32/imagen-paisagem-hd-live-wallpaper-2-0thumb.jpg) repeat;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: 100%;
    height: 300px;
    
    opacity: 0.2; /* usando opacidade */
}
```

```html
<div>
    <img src='http://static-files.cdnandroid.com/1f/48/ef/32/imagen-paisagem-hd-live-wallpaper-2-0thumb.jpg' alt='minha imagem' />
</div>
```

Agora o mesmo exemplo utilizando `linear-gradient`:

```css
div {
    background:
        /*aplicando linear gradient*/
        linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7) 0%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7) 100%),
        /* e a imagem de background */
        url(http://static-files.cdnandroid.com/1f/48/ef/32/imagen-paisagem-hd-live-wallpaper-2-0thumb.jpg);
    
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: 100%;
    height: 300px;
}
```

```html
<div>
    <img src='http://static-files.cdnandroid.com/1f/48/ef/32/imagen-paisagem-hd-live-wallpaper-2-0thumb.jpg' alt='minha imagem' />
</div>
```

Você pode mesclar vários valores no atributo `background` separando-os por vírgula, por exemplo:

```
background: linear-gradient(to top, rgba(255,255,255,0.5) 0%, rgba(255,255,255,0.5) 100%),
            url("url_da_imagem");
```

--

Referência: https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/CSS/Multiple_backgrounds

Answer (score 0):

Você pode simular que a imagem esta dentro do elemento background, mas quando na realidade ela esta fora e apenas posicionada sobre ele, assim pode aplicar a transparência no "fundo" sem afetar a imagem na frente.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="jumbo-destaque">
    <div style="background-image: url(http://drop.studiogt.com.br/g8/img/berinjela-tomato.png)"></div>
    <img src="http://drop.studiogt.com.br/g8/img/berinjela-tomato.png">
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.jumbo-destaque {
    position:relative;
    width:640px;
    height:360px;
}
.jumbo-destaque div {
    background-size: cover;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    opacity: 0.5;
}
.jumbo-destaque IMG {
    position:absolute;
    border: 8px solid #fff;
    top: calc(50% - (320px /2));
    left: calc(50% - (471px /2));
}
```

Veja exemplo no [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jaderw/1L1frw1u/)